# call isset from function inside class

Tags: php, function, class

I have not been able to find out how to do this, but I think that it can be done.

I want to receive information about name (`$ime`) and display `drugiDio()` after I get that. I am using `isset` as I also want to not display `prviDio()` after input of name, but I think that that part I can find alone.

Here is the code I tried:

```
<?php
class igra {
    function prviDio() {
        global $lang;
        $kreni = $lang['kreni'];
        echo "<h1>".$lang['naslov']."</h1><p>".$lang['opis']."</p>";
        echo '<form metod="post">'
            .$lang['unesite-ime'].
            '<input name="ime" type="text" id="ime" size="40" maxlength="40" /><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="kreni" value="'.$kreni.'" /></form>';
    }
    function drugiDio() {
        global $lang;
        $ime=$_GET['ime'];
        echo $lang['vase-ime']. $ime;
    }
}

$igra = new igra;
echo $igra->prviDio();
if(isset($igra->$_GET['kreni'])) {
    echo $igra->drugiDio();
}
?>
```

What can I do with this for it to work?:

```
if(isset($igra->$_GET['kreni'])) {
    echo $igra->drugiDio();
}
```

I also tried

```
if(isset($igra->_GET['kreni'])) {
    echo $igra->drugiDio();
}
```

and many other combinations but none of them don't work...

Text from variables is in language files. This is just the PHP part. On the page everything is visible, and it works fine when I echo name without `isset()` like `echo $igra->drugiDio();`.

Comment: What is $_GET['kreni']?  $_GET is a superglobal, you don't need to access it as a class property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

```
if(isset($_GET['kreni'])) {
echo $igra->drugiDio();
}
```

Note: 
$_GET and $_POST are `superglobal` variables so you can access them directly, provided that they are set. For more information please read the [manual here.](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Comment: I believe he is trying to check if his $igra class has a member whose name is passed in in $_GET['kreni'].  i.e if you passed in 'foo', he wants to see if $igra->foo is set before calling $igra->drugiDio()

Comment: @fbas, as far as I understand, @lkerepc is trying to determine whether the user is entered his name. Look at the code: $_GET['kreni'] is something like "submit". So, if the form from the `prviDio` method is submitted, he wants to echo a name of the user (probably), which is $_GET['ime'].

Comment: you are probably right. I was probably looking too much into it.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I wanted. I didn't know it is superglobal variable. It work now.

Comment: @fbas I would like that too. But I just started to learn and I would try do things like that by myself as long as I can :)